# is it possible to use Telegrams MTproto Proxy as a system proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, telegram-messenger

Is it possible to use Telegram's [MTproto Proxies](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/MTProxy) other than just in telegram. for example, for browsing or as system proxy. MTproto proxies seems to be very fast and working very well inside telegram, so it came to my mind that maybe i can use them as a system proxy.

Comment: Which operating system ? Windows ?

Comment: @harrymc yes windows, but it could be others too.

Comment: This is a proxy for accessing Telegram services. I very much doubt it could connect to anything else, provided it actually is a HTTP forward proxy in the first place.

Comment: Highly unlikely that software written for the Telegram environment could function in other environments.

Comment: @DanielB yes I thought so too. But I wasn't sure either. I thought maybe there is a core or something to use the MTproto

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say something is "impossible" because it is difficult to prove a negative.

However, it is possible to say that such a thing as you are considering is "improbable". It is improbable because this product is designed for a single specific purpose, and that purpose is not the one you are considering.

It is POSSIBLE that this tool is actually broadly applicable and has arguments you could discover that would allow it to function beyond its current implementation, but, that is beyond the scope of this site.

As MTProto is currently implemented, it exists to enable a single, specific application to behave in a specific way. If Telegram documented additional functions and licensed MTProto for use elsewhere, you'd be free to explore that. As neither of those are true, you are not free to explore that, and what you are imagining remains improbable.